# Create SHA-1 checksum from tarfile

Tags: node.js, cryptography, tar, sha1

I am using [archiver](https://www.archiverjs.com/) to create a tarfile server side.

```
const tar = archiver('tar', {
  zlib: { level: 9 },
  gzip: true
})

tar.append('console.log(42);', {
  name: `script.js`
})

tar.finalize()

tar.pipe(...)
```

---

How can i create a SHA-1 checksum from the tar, as described in the documentation for the [NPM Registry](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/responses/package-metadata.md#dist)?

I think i can use the [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto) module, but i am unsure of the details of the implementation.

The shasum should look something like

```
bbf102d5ae73afe2c553295e0fb02230216f65b1
```

Comment: Uh, the best way is probably to create a `ReadableStream` or `WritableStream` and put that between the generated pipe and the file stream. Then you can use any SHA-1 implementation to update the hash, until the stream is closed. This is more of a general direction than an answer...